# Restangular: Empty array using $object

Tags: angularjs, html, restangular

I display my data in a table (smart-table)  and everything is working well but in my angular code, when I try to get my "topicList" it's return an empty array. there is my code and thank you in advance.

```
$scope.topicList= Restangular.all("topic").getList().$object;
    for(var k in $scope.topicList) {
        console.log($scope.topicList[k]);
    if($scope.topicList[k] === "")
        {xxxx} 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Restangular.all('topic').getList().then(function(response) {
  $scope.topicList = response;
  ...
});
```

After you've assigned the topicList then you can do your bits and pieces.